# Illegal string offset en PHP

Tags: php

estoy tratando de generar un script PHP en el que me muestre los datos de proveedores cargados en una tabla MySQL.
La idea es que se vea como una especie de PERFIL del proveedor, para luego imprimirlo o simplemente tener una visión más sintetizada de sus datos.

En principio, los tengo todos ordenados en una tabla, en donde el nombre está configurado como un link que me llevaría al mencionado PERFIL.

Dicho link, lo quiero hacer con la variable $_GET, pero no logro dar con la forma correcta de formular el script para poder acceder a todos los datos relacionados al nombre del proveedor.

El script que (más o menos) estoy formulando, es el siguiente:

```
<?php 
include "conexion.php";

$proveedor = "SELECT * FROM proveedores WHERE nombre = \"$_GET[nombre]\";";
$query = $con->query($proveedor);
while (mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo $proveedor["nombre"];
    echo $proveedor["id"];
    }
?>
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'nombre' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\estudiomanager.com\system\php\seleccionar_proveedor.php
>   on line 8 S Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\estudiomanager.com\system\php\seleccionar_proveedor.php
>   on line 9 S

La línea 8 y 9 corresponden a los `echo` en donde estoy tratando de devolver todos los datos de un mismo proveedor.

La idea es devolver todos los datos de la fila correspondiente al nombre del proveedor, para luego darles forma de PERFIL, por así decirlo.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Porque pones `$proveedor` dentro del while?, si todavía php no ejecuta la sentencia en la base de datos, creo que lo correcto sería que ponga lo que estas recorriendo como en ese caso sería `$query`. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias!, cambié las variables, y el resultado es el siguiente: _ Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La variable `$proveedor` no la puedes utilizar dentro del `while`, tienes que almacenar `mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)` en una variable. Intenta no mezclar programación orientado a objetos con estilos por procedimientos. Ademas te aconsejo utilizar `mysqli_fetch_array()` en vez de `mysqli_fetch_all()` por tema de rendimiento, ya que solo vamos a trabajar con las filas de un resultado.

Te pongo tu ejemplo con los cambios aplicados:

```
<?php 
    include "conexion.php";

    $proveedor = "SELECT * FROM proveedores WHERE nombre = \"$_GET[nombre]\";";
    $resultado = $con->query($proveedor);

    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);){
        echo $fila["nombre"];
        echo $fila["id"];
    }
?>
```

Otro punto aparte de tu problema, es que tu consulta es vulnerable a ataques de inyecciones `SQL`.Para evitar dichos ataques se recomiendan las sentencias preparadas. Puedes ver mas información en este [enlace](https://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Gracias, así funciona perfecto. Hay un semicolon de más al final de la línea del while que no va, pero fuera de eso, funciona. Respecto de la vulnerabilidad, la estoy aplicando a medida que los scripts me funcionan de manera simple. Muchas gracias por el aporte!

Comment: @JoseManuelBorras Me alegra que mi respuesta te haya servido!

Answer (score 3):

Creo que primero deberías verificar que está viniendo algo en tu variable `$_GET`, por lo cual te recomiendo verificarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
if(isset($_GET["nombre"])) {

  $nombre = $_GET["nombre"];

}else{

  $nombre = "no hay nada en nombre";
  echo $nombre;

}
```

Y luego cambiar tu consulta por:

```
$proveedor = "SELECT * FROM proveedores WHERE nombre = $nombre ";
```

Creo que de esta manera te debe salir. De lo contrario mira en la parte superior de tu pantalla, si te sale un mensaje tipo: "no hay nada en nombre" es que el error está en tu formulario. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Prueba hacerlo así

```html
    <?php 
    include "conexion.php";



    /* Virificamos si se envia el valor nombre por GET  */
    if(isset($_GET['nombre'])){
      $nombre =$_GET['nombre'];
      $proveedor = "SELECT * FROM proveedores WHERE nombre ='$nombre'";
      $query = $con->query($proveedor);
      while (mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo $proveedor["nombre"];
        echo $proveedor["id"];
      }
    }else{
      echo = "No has enviado el nombre por la URL";
    }


    ?>
```

para enviar el valor por parámetro desde la lista deberías hacer algo así.

```
<a href="perfildelproveedor.php?nombre='<?=$nombre?>'"/>
```

De cualquier manera debieras utilizar el ID (codigo) del proveedor para hacer la búsqueda  ya que es mas rápido